# counter (for loop?) through XML in powershell

Tags: xml, azure, powershell

I have a basic XML array at the top of my powershell script.  Future plans call for me having this be a separate file that I call in, but for now this works:

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PublicSubnets>
<Subnet>15.4.211.0/16</Subnet>
<Subnet>15.4.211.0/24</Subnet>
<Subnet>15.4.211.0/24</Subnet>
<Subnet>15.4.211.0/24</Subnet>
<Subnet>15.4.211.0/24</Subnet>
</PublicSubnets>
"@
```

I'm trying to call this, and go through a loop wherein there's a 'priority' and 'counter', that go up each time the loop completes.

For example, I'm hoping to have the following

```
15.4.211.0/16   counter=1   priority=250
15.4.211.0/24   counter=2   priority=251
15.4.211.0/24   counter=3   priority=252
```

The idea is i'm going to be creating NSG rules in Azure based on these, and if I can get the counter and priority correct, I can automate the NSG rules being added (counter would be the rule number, priority would be the rule priority).

Currently here's what I have (remember I have the XML array at the top of the powershell script)

```
$priority = 250
$counter = 1
foreach ($subnet in $xml.PublicSubnets)
{
$subnet.Subnet
Write-output "Counter is $counter and Priority is $priority"
$counter++
$priority++
}
```

Instead of my hoped for output (see above), i'm getting this:

```
15.4.211.0/16
15.4.211.0/24
15.4.211.0/24
15.4.211.0/24
15.4.211.0/24
Counter is 1 and Priority is 250
```

If I run it again, the counter and priority have gone up by 1, but that doesn't help me :(

Am I going about this the right way?  I'm not a programmer, and new to powershell.  I've watched and read tutorials, but could really use some help here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only entering your `foreach` loop *once*, for the one and only `<PublicSubnets>` element; inside the loop, `$subnet.Subnet` is then the *array* of *all* `<Subnet>` elements.

Instead, you need to loop over `$xml.PublicSubnets.Subnet` - the individual `<Subnet>` elements - directly:

```
$priority = 250
$counter = 1
foreach ($subnet in $xml.PublicSubnets.Subnet) {
  "$subnet   counter=$counter   priority=$priority"
  $counter++
  $priority++
}
```

With your sample document, this yields:

```
15.4.211.0/16   counter=1   priority=250
15.4.211.0/24   counter=2   priority=251
15.4.211.0/24   counter=3   priority=252
15.4.211.0/24   counter=4   priority=253
15.4.211.0/24   counter=5   priority=254
```

Comment: My pleasure, @S.Space; glad to hear it helped.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$priority = 250
$counter = 1
foreach ($subnet in $xml.PublicSubnets.Subnet)
{
$subnet.Subnet
Write-output "Counter is $counter and Priority is $priority"
$counter+=1
$priority+=1
}
```

Comment: It is only now that I realize that your answer works too: the lack of pointing out the crucial change from `$xml.PublicSubnets` to `$xml.PublicSubnets.Subnet` in the loop condition and changing unrelated parts of the code (`++`) made me miss that fact.
Can I suggest pointing such things out as part of your answers in the future? In this particular case, I wouldn't have written my own answer, had I recognized that your solution works.

Comment: I appreciate it.  Thank you very much.